# Cambiar URLs con parámetros por "URLs amigables"

Tags: php, nginx

He desarrollado una web con PHP, MySQL, CSS, Javascript y HTML. El problema que me encuentro es que cuando haces las páginas dinámicas las URLs suelen ser como ésta:

> /pruebas.php?ID=2
>   /panel.php?ID=7&GENERO=2 
>   /especifica.php?ID=326&GENERO=2&CATEGORIA=7

Y claro, todo esto no le gusta mucho a google.

Quería saber si cabe la posibilidad de eliminar las extensiones `.php` y crear url amigables.

Uso un servidor **NGINX**.

**Mi archivo .conf que carga la web:**

```
server {
 listen 8360;
 listen [::]:8360;

 root /var/www/laboratorio/;

 # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
 index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

 server_name 82.223.13.57;

 location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg)$ { expires 365d; } location ~* \.(css|js|pdf)$ { expires 30d; }

 location ~ ^/.well-known {
    allow all;
 }

 location / {
 # First attempt to serve request as file, then
 # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
 try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 error_page 405 = $uri;
 }

 # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 #
 location ~ \.php$ {
 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 location ~ /\.ht {
  deny all;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay multitud de marcos de trabajo que usan "URLs amigables" y en sus webs muestran la configuración típica para este tipo de escenarios.

Para empezar, deberías crear un único archivo PHP de entrada que llamaremos "enrutador". Será el script encargado de recoger todas las peticiones HTTP y llamar al PHP adecuado atendiendo a los parámetros entregados a él.

En Slim, por ejemplo, [las instrucciones para "reescribir" las URLs están aquí](https://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/#nginx):

```
server {
    listen ...; server_name ...; root ...;

    # Esto es lo más importante:
    try_files $uri /index.php;

    location /index.php {
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 3s;     # default of 60s is just too long
        fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;       # default of 60s is just too long
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;    # assumes you are running php-fpm locally on port 9000
    }
}
```

La "magia" se crea en esta línea:

```
try_files $uri /index.php;
```

Primero intenta, si existe, cargar el archivo CSS, JS o imagen del sistema de archivos. En caso de no existir pasa la petición al enrutador (`index.php`).

Además, puedes crear una regla de archivo única para PHP como se sugiere en el archivo de configuración (en vez de patrón de archivo que termine en `.php`):

```
location /index.php { ... }
```

Tu enrutador recibirá la petición con la URL en `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Debes analizar esa variable en busca de qué PHP ejecutar y qué parámetros pasarle.

---

### Edición:

Con los datos adicionales proporcionados en la pregunta puedo sugerirte las siguientes modificaciones:

### Captura de peticiones

Tienes dos opciones para conseguirlo.

Usando `try_files`:

```
location / {
 # First attempt to serve request as file, then
 # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
 # Si quieres permitir parámetros GET fuera del control del enrutador:
 try_files $uri $uri/ /enrutador.php$is_args$args;
 error_page 405 = $uri;
 }
```

Usando `error_page`:

```
error_page  404 /enrutador.php;
```

### Enrutador de peticiones

Para maximizar la compatibilidad con tu aplicación existente deberías crear un script como punto de entrada al resto de tus scripts PHP, modificando los parámetros `GET` de acuerdo con el contenido de la URL.

Ejemplo de archivo `enrutador.php`:

```
<?php
// Comprobamos el patrón /pruebas/id-descripción
if (preg_match('#^/pruebas/([0-9]+)(-.*)?$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $parametros) === 1) {
  $_GET['ID'] = $parametros[1];
  require_once 'pruebas.php';
  exit;
}

// Comprobamos el patrón /panel/id/genero-descripción
if (preg_match('#^/panel/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(-.*)?$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $parametros) === 1) {
  $_GET['ID'] = $parametros[1];
  $_GET['GENERO'] = $parametros[2];
  require_once 'panel.php';
  exit;
}

// Comprobamos el patrón /especifica/id/genero/categoria-descripción
if (preg_match('#^/especifica/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)(-.*)?$#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $parametros) === 1) {
  $_GET['ID'] = $parametros[1];
  $_GET['GENERO'] = $parametros[2];
  $_GET['CATEGORIA'] = $parametros[3];
  require_once 'especifica.php';
  exit;
}

// Enviamos un código de error HTTP 404 (página no encontrada)
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die('Página no encontrada');
```

### Ejemplos de URLs admitidas

Estos son ejemplos de tus URLs comparadas con las admitidas por el enrutador:

- /pruebas.php?ID=2
- /pruebas/2
- /pruebas/2-el-coloso-en-llamas
- /panel.php?ID=7&GENERO=2
- /panel/7/2
- /panel/7/2-lo-que-el-viento-se-llevó
- /especifica.php?ID=326&GENERO=2&CATEGORIA=7
- /panel/7/2/7
- /panel/7/2/7-ponyo-en-el-acantilado

Como puedes ver, las descripciones pueden ser arbitrarias y son las que ayudarán al buscador a entender el contenido de tus URLs.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia gracias por tu respuesta. Viendo la documentación del `Slim`  entiendo que por ejemplo que en el archivo `nginx.conf` tendria que añadir esto: `/var/www/
    laboratorio/ <-- Document root!
        index.php <-- I instantiate Slim here!
    lib/
        Slim/ <-- I store Slim lib files here!` Es correcto?

Comment: Y luego en el archivo.conf que carga mi web añadir lo de `try_files $uri /index.php;` y el location? es así?.

Comment: Creo que puede que entienda algo!. Lo que hace lo que has hecho es que si pongo `pruebas` sin php ni nada automáticamente se va al index.php, cierto?

Comment: No, no es así. La documentación de Slim habla sobre su estructura de archivos y directorios. Tú puedes seguir usando la tuya. Las diferencias importantes (sobre todo la primera) están explicadas más abajo.

Comment: Como he visto que has agregado más información a tu pregunta, más tarde conectaré para facilitarte un ejemplo más específico. Por cierto, por favor, pon en tu pregunta cómo querrías tener tus urls.

Comment: Vale perfecto @OscarGarcia lo pongo. haber si logro entenderlo

Comment: pero cuando son varias variables, como se construye ahí un URL?? pongo la más simple si es `/pruebas.php?ID=2` me muestra las pruebas de con relación a los `hombres` pero siendo la misma `/pruebas.php?ID=1` me mostraria las pruebas de mujer. Si tu pones ahí que eso se llama /pruebas  como distingue cual tiene que abrir? y esa es la más facíl, las demás aun las veo más complejas. Siendo así no se como ponerte como quiero las Url. gracias

Comment: Me queda una hora para poder actualizar esta respuesta. Te pondré ejemplos con las urls de la pregunta.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias @OscarGarcia

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia a pasado una hora, sucede algo?? gracias!

Comment: Pasa que crear un entorno para reproducir tu problema lleva su tiempo: https://github.com/ojgarciab/plantilla-gitpod-nginx-php [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107326/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-miguel).